# Browser halt for the site during file download

Tags: php, header

I have small chunk of code that helps to download a file. But the site not opened/work during file download, but when i open the site on other browser then its working. I don't have any idea what going on with the browser during file download. Here are the headers that i am using to download a zip file:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");                        
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$zipname."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
//header("Content-Length: ".filesize($directory_location . '/' . $zipname));

ob_end_flush();


readfile($directory_location . '/' . $zipname);
ob_end_clean();
```

Even i don't know how to debug it, so that i get the weak point from my codes.

Comment: Never use `Expires = 0` to prevent caching

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia what is the drawback of `Expires = 0`? or why do i can't?

Comment: The Expires header is sent by the remote server and passed through to the browser by the Portal Server. Unless the time on all three machines is synchronized, an Expires=0 header can mistakenly return cached content. To solve this problem, set the Expires header to a fixed date that is definitely in the past

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia do you mean like this http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#example-4474

Comment: Are you using sessions? If so, an “open” session blocks other scripts from accessing the session while your download script is running. `session_write_close` before streaming the file content to the client fixes that.

Comment: @CBroe i am using session to check the user role before download, Can i have to use `session_write_close` after checking the user role?

Comment: @jogesh_pi yes, now you are goggling...means will sort out problem soon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since you are using sessions:

An “open” session blocks other scripts from accessing the session while your download script is running.

`session_write_close` before streaming the file content to the client fixes that. Just call it after you are done with checking whatever you need to check in the session, and before the time-consuming part of the script begins – that will release the lock on the session, and other scripts that are called while the download script is running can access the session again.